# Can this query be written on MS SQL server? The query works on MySQL but does not give the desired output on MS SQL Server

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Task is to list the CITY(column) names from STATION(tablename) that either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels. I have solved it using substring function. The code below accomplishes the task on MySQL server but gives different Output on MS SQL SERVER.

I have tried finding the difference between the MySQL and MS SQL Servers. But could not figure out what is the issue.

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY FROM STATION WHERE SUBSTRING(CITY,1,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U')OR 
SUBSTRING(LOWER(CITY),-1,1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

I expect Columns which either do not start with vowels or do not end with vowels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SUBSTRING()` behaves differently in SQL Server because of the negative starting position in:

```
SUBSTRING(LOWER(CITY),-1,1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017:

> If start is less than 1, the returned expression will begin at the
>   first character that is specified in expression. In this case, the
>   number of characters that are returned is the largest value of either
>   the sum of start + length- 1 or 0.

So a negative starting position like -1 does not mean that it will return the last character of the string.
But you can get it with the function `RIGHT()`:

```
...OR RIGHT(LOWER(CITY), 1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite it as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CITY 
FROM STATION 
WHERE LEFT(CITY,1) NOT IN ('A','E','I','O','U') 
  AND RIGHT(CITY,1) NOT IN ('a','e','i','o','u');
```